# Array not being passed to Function Method

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop

I'm currently trying to pass an array of (values[3]) which it's first 3 values contain user input. However, I'm getting the error "expected int* but argument is type of int". I've tried to pass to method1, without the iteration of 'i', using the first three positions in the values array, but that's as far as I managed to attempt to fix it, any help would be much appreciated!

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int values[3];

    printf("Enter three consecutive numbers (With spaces between)");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&values[0],&values[1],&values[2]);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    method1(values[i]);
}

int method1(int values[3])
{

}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` remove. then just `method1(values);`

Comment: That still proceeds to give me the same error.

Comment: Have you prototype declaration?

Comment: http://ideone.com/trzzcn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass an array to a function as an array - it "decays" to a pointer. There are two issues with your code:

- There is no forward declaration of `method1` visible at the point of invocation, and
- You are passing `values[i]`, a *scalar* value in place of an array.

A forward declaration is necessary because otherwise the compiler would assume that `method1` takes an returns an `int`, which is not true. Add this line before `main`

```
int method1(int values[]);
```

You could also move `method1` above `main` to fix this without providing a forward declaration. Also, `3` inside square brackets is not necessary, because the array is passed like a pointer anyway.

If you want to pass the entire array, pass `values`. Of course, `i` becomes unnecessary:

```
int res = method1(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int values[3];

    printf("Enter three consecutive numbers (With spaces between)");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&values[0],&values[1],&values[2]);

    method1(values, 3);    
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int method1(int* values, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

In C, arrays are passed by reference, you can see method1's first argument is int* that refers first element of array, and second argument is size of this array.